# add effect to opening camera preview in android

Tags: android, effects, android-camera

is there a tutorial to make a face booth application in `android` ,
 or how to add an effect to the opening camera preview, can any one put me on the right
 direction .

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what effect you like to have. You can put an overlay over surface  view displaying camera preview images, and this oevrlay can contain images with alpha channel.   There could be some weird parameters for specific camera immplementations,   but this is not portable and will not work for other vendors

Comment: i want to add a convex effect

Comment: I doubt it is possible without cooperation of native camera application.  Camera preview is rendered on the surface view via direct memory transfer,  bypassing your application altogether.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PreviewCallback.html